# Strange behavior of Enumerator.MoveNext()

Tags: c#, infinite-loop, enumerator

Could someone explain why this code is running in infinity loop? Why `MoveNext()` return `true` always?

```
var x = new { TempList = new List<int> { 1, 3, 6, 9 }.GetEnumerator() };
while (x.TempList.MoveNext())
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[`List<T>.GetEnumerator()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yss765) returns a mutable value type ([`List<T>.Enumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x854yt9s)). You're storing that value in the anonymous type.

Now, let's have a look at what this does:

```
while (x.TempList.MoveNext())
{
    // Ignore this
}
```

That's equivalent to:

```
while (true)
{
    var tmp = x.TempList;
    var result = tmp.MoveNext();
    if (!result)
    {
        break;
    }

    // Original loop body
}
```

Now note what we're calling `MoveNext()` on - the *copy* of the value which is in the anonymous type. You can't actually change the value in the anonymous type - all you've got is a property you can call, which will give you a copy of the value.

If you change the code to:

```
var x = new { TempList = (IEnumerable<int>) new List<int> { 1, 3, 6, 9 }.GetEnumerator() };
```

... then you'll end up getting a *reference* in the anonymous type. A reference to a box containing the mutable value. When you call `MoveNext()` on that reference, the value inside the box will be mutated, so it'll do what you want.

For analysis on a very similar situation (again using `List<T>.GetEnumerator()`) see [my 2010 blog post "Iterate, damn you!"](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/07/27/iterate-damn-you/).

Comment: I'm looking at this and having trouble figuring out which element here is a value type for which the copy/reference distinction actually makes a difference.

Comment: i didnt got it, how it works fine if we cast it to ``IEnumerable<int>``?? @JonSkeet can you explain it more in simple words

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: When the compile-time type of `TempList` is `IEnumerable<int>`, access to it just copies a reference. Acting on that reference will mutate the boxed value, and next time you copy a reference it will still refer to the same boxed value, so you see the change. Compare that with copying the value type value and mutating that copy - when you *next* copy the original value, you won't see the previous change.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: The compile-time type of `TempList` is `List<T>.Enumerator`, which is a value type.

Comment: I often hear _"Don't use `foreach` in critical-path code, because each use requires allocating an `Enumerator`."_  For this reason, I always assumed `Enumerator`s were reference-types.  If they are `struct`s, does that mean that advice is incorrect?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: It can be, yes - but it depends on the implementation. That performance reason is precisely *why* `List<T>.Enumerator` is a struct... but don't forget that it only helps if the compile-time type of the variable is `List<T>`. If it's just `IEnumerable<T>`, the `GetEnumerator()` method has to return `IEnumerator<T>`, so any value type enumerator will be boxed.

Answer (score 3):

While the `foreach` construct in C# and the `For Each` loop in VB.NET are often used with types that implement `IEnumerable<T>`, they will accept any type which includes a `GetEnumerator` method whose return type provides a suitable `MoveNext` function and `Current` property.  Having `GetEnumerator` return a value type will in many cases allow `foreach` to be implemented more efficiently than would be possible if it returned `IEnumerator<T>`.

Unfortunately, because there is no means by which a type can supply a value-type enumerator when invoked from `foreach` without also supplying one when invoked by a `GetEnumerator` method call, the authors of `List<T>` faced a slight trade-off of performance versus semantics.  At the time, because C# did not support variable-type inference, any code using the value returned from `List<T>.GetEnumerator` would have to declare a variable of type `IEnumerator<T>` or `List<T>.Enumerator`.  Code using the former type would behave as though `List<T>.Enumerator` was a reference type, and a programmer using the latter could be presumed to realize that it was a structure type.  When C# added type inference, however, that assumption ceased to hold.  Code could very easily end up using type `List<T>.Enumerator` without the programmer knowing of that type's existence.

If C# were ever to define a struct-method attribute which could be used to tag methods which shouldn't be invokable on read-only structures, and if `List<T>.Enumerator` made use of it, code such as yours could properly yield a compile-time error on the call to `MoveNext` rather that yielding bogus behavior.  I know of no particular plans to add such an attribute, however.